# Failed to decode downloaded font Sans Pro

Tags: css, fonts

In Chrome, I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to decode downloaded font:
>   https://fonts.gstatic.com/stats/Source+Sans+Pro/normal/600

I see that there are other questions about this but in my case it's NOT font awesome and it's not a font that's FTP'ed. It's a direct link to Google:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And, in the CSS file, there seems to be simple references to the font:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro" !important;
}
```

Any idea what may be causing this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: A q&d test shows it works here. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Of if that fails, a link to the website?

Comment: Error could be cause by broken path files. Check the google file path to ensure that font exist. More so a hard reload to clear cached font if possible